# Is there an antibuddha?

Tags: suffering, evil

Is there a figure in Buddhism corresponding to the Christian notion of such? And what would that mean, practically?

Comment: I take it that you mean a figure like the Christian notion of Satan. Or is the anti-Christ unlike Satan?

Comment: Also I guess when you say "practically" I gather that you're not interested in historical events of figures (e.g. analogous to Satan tempting Jesus in the desert), but rather what is the effect on present-day practice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One to one comparison with Satan is not possible, but there's an angel called Mara who dislikes the existence of the Buddha, Dhamma and Sangha. He tries to stop beings from attaining enlightenment.

Answer (score 1):

**Mara** its name is Mara. It can be understood as unconscious desires of Buddha or as a literal being who comes to fight with him and does not want to get him enlightened.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't work. The Buddha is a dependently originated entity, therefore in finality empty. An antibuddha would have to be full, but not anatta is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pachcheka buddha - The one superior is the buddha.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the word anti- as it is used in Physics then no there is no anti Buddha. In physics anti-proton or anti-electron are valid particles which when meet with their counter proton or electron they get annihilated i.e particle and its anti particle annihilate each other releasing energy.  The particles die. 
But Buddha has no anti Buddha. Nothing can neutralize Buddha. Whether after death Buddha exists or does not exist is not known. 
However if you are using anti- for something or someone who opposes Buddha then yes there is Mara who opposes Buddha and everyone who chooses the path of enlightenment. Mara is not just anti-Buddha , he is anti-enlightenment.